# Why is data tranfsfer unpredictable using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR?

Tags: opencl

In the book OpenCL by action the author says on pn0: 46 that:

```
If you want the buffer object to access the same
memory referenced by the host pointer, set  CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR . This is memory-
efficient, but there’s a drawback. Data transfer between hosts and devices can be
unpredictable, so you may not be able to safely access the host pointer memory after
communication starts.
```

I am not able to understand why this data transfer will be unpredictable and why I may not be able to safely access the host pointer memory after communication starts? What is the point  author is trying to make here?

**Example usage:**

```
cl_int err;
int a[16];
cl_mem newBuffer = clCreateBuffer(
context,
CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,
16*sizeof(int),
a,
&err);
if( err !¼ CL_SUCCESS ) {
// Do whatever error test is necessary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the author is intending to communicate.

The rules for host / device memory access are clear: Once you've handed it over (using `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`) then you can only access it on the host *after* `clEnqueueMapBuffer` (with blocking or waiting on the event or `clFinish`). Then after accessing it on the host side, you *must* `clEnqueueUnmapMemObject` before accessing it on the device. Note: You can also use `CL_ALLOC_HOST_PTR` instead and let the OpenCL runtime do the allocation; the rules after that remain the same.

Comment: #Dithermaster Thanks for your message. But can you tell me which one is faster and why?

Comment: What is the point in mapping Device-side memory space into Host-side memory space, if Device is using memory from Host?

Comment: @user2799508: typically same speed

Comment: @Roman Arzumanyan - Device only uses Host memory if it's a unified architecture (I.E. iGPU not dGPU). Otherwise they have separate memory pools with the PCIE buss between them and mapping from one to the other allows you to pretend that they're the same.

Comment: @DavidSauter - I'm not speaking about memory objects handling, which is transparent to user. The idea, that same memory on Host side can potentially have two different virtual addresses (first, returned by alloc and second, returned by clEnqueueMapBuffer) looks strange to me. That's it.

Comment: If you use `ALLOC_HOST_PTR` the value returned from clCreateBuffer is not a host pointer; you need to use `clEnqueueMapBuffer` to get the host pointer. If you use `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` and pass in a pointer allocated using `malloc` the OpenCL runtime has the option of _copying_ the host memory into the OpenCL allocated memory. Then the pointer returned from `clEnqueueMapBuffer` would be different than the pointer you got from `malloc`. Clear as mud?

Comment: If you use `ALLOC_HOST_PTR` then you are asking OpenCL to allocate host memory for that buffer.  You can feel free to hold onto the pointer to that buffer but touching it when you're not between a map/unmap is undefined (nasal deamon level undefined).  To test this use `ALLOC_HOST_PTR` then compare it with the pointer that map gives you back.  So long as you're not mapping with an offset you should get exactly the same pointer back.  If you don't please let me know what implementation you are on so I can file a bug report.